# Large number of entities in DBContext fetches very slow in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, poco

I'm trying to create a generic DBContext for one of our database. It has over 1500 entities and I'm trying to create all of them in a single DBContext. It created perfectly fine. Now, I'm trying to access an entity (Table) to fetch records, and it takes about 2 minutes to load. That table has only 16 rows. I think thats a huge amount of time. If I create the DbContext will smaller entities, it works faster.

How do I make a DbContext with large eneties work faster? Any suggestions would help.

Comment: https://neverindoubtnet.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/squash-entity-framework-startup-time.html

Comment: Try to `Dapper`